# flutter internationalizing with flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

Bloc is good because it works without context. Internalization requires context. You can try to pass it to the block, but in my case, the bloc is initialized before the internalization. MultiProvider before MaterialApp, how to change the sequence and use internalization inside bloc?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    StartPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => new StartPage(),
    EditorPage.routeName: (BuildContext context) => new EditorPage(),
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
  //localization always == null
  var localization = S.of(context);
   
   return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: ChannelModel(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<InternetBloc>(
            create: (context) => InternetBloc(localizations: localization),
          ),
          BlocProvider<MultiBloc>(
            create: (context) => MultiBloc(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<DbBloc>(
            create: (context) => DbBloc(),
          ),
          BlocProvider<FileBloc>(
            create: (context) => FileBloc(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          localizationsDelegates: [
            S.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: S.delegate.supportedLocales,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: StartPage(),
          routes: routes,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: To me, internationalization is related to the UI layer, so I never put any context inside BLoC. Maybe it would help if you explain what you want to achieve with that.

Comment: I understand what you mean. My problem, translate errors from dio http package  into different languages, dio is inside the bloc, internalization does not work there. My solution was to create a separate class of exceptions, denote errors with numbers like unique id,  transfer error codes to the UI, parse errors codes and translate them there.

Comment: So you can write a helper method/class where you pass the context and ID, then translate the error based on that. But still, what should come back from BLoC is only the error ID, you would still need to do that parsing in the UI layer.